# rewrite url for image files in codeigniter or htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I need a solution for rewriting the image file path in codeigniter or htaccess. Below I have given how the redirect url should be. I am using a routers file to rewrite other urls.  Please help me with this.

original path
http://example.com/assets/upload/subfolder/1389242332.jpg

rewrite path
http://example.com/static/images/1389242332.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^static/images\/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg))?$ assets/upload/subfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

It will replace URLs containing 'static/images' to 'assets/upload/subfolder/'.